# Background processes in the aiohttp event loop

Tags: python-3.x, celery, aiohttp

I have a web service that accepts post requests. A post request specifies a specific job to be executed in the background, that modifies a database used for later analysis. The sender of the request does not care about the result, and only needs to receive a 202 acknowledgment from the web service.

How it was implemented so far:
Flask Web service will get the http request , and add the necessary parameters to the task queue (rq workers), and return back an acknowledgement. A separate rq worker process listens on the queue and processes the job.

We have now switched to aiohttp, and realized that the web service can now schedule the actual job request in its own event loop, by using the aiohttp.ensure_future() method.

This however blurs the lines between the web-server and the task queue. On the positive side, it eliminates the need of having to manage the rq workers.

Is this considered a good practice?

Comment: Maybe you can use `asyncio.gather` in order to gather 2 coroutines together ant then await for the results...

Answer (score 0):

If your tasks are not CPU heavy - yes, it is good practice.
But if so, then you need to move them to separate service or use `run_in_executor()`. In other case your aiohttp event loop will be blocked by this tasks and server will not be able to accept new requests.